# MySql Number of appointment by user based on DATE

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin, group-by

I would like to know how many appointment taken by particular user in ONE DAY.

table A

Date_time                    user_id

2014-08-25 21:00:00           1

2014-08-25 01:00:00           1

2014-08-25 03:00:00           2

2014-08-25 16:00:00           1

2014-08-26 015:00:00           1

2014-08-26 011:00:00           2

2014-08-26 010:00:00           2

2014-08-26 010:00:00           1

TABLE B

user_id      user_name

1            xyz

2            abc

RESULT SHOULD BE

USER   DATE      NUMBER OF APP

xyz    2014-08-25      3

abc    2014-08-25      1

xyz    2014-08-26      2

abc    2014-08-26      2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select b.user_name `USER`,date_format(a.Date_Time,'%Y-%m-%d') `DATE`, count(a.user_id)  `NUMBER OF APP`
from `TABLE A` a
inner join `TABLE B` b on a.user_id = b.user_id
group by a.user_id, date_format(a.Date_Time,'%Y-%m-%d')
```